# Chart working only in chrome, not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm using a kendo chart to show the time format. My code as follows, I'm following their documentation to do that. its as follows. [Kendo Display Time on Value Axis](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/various/display-time-on-value-axis)

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var arry = [{"TimeSlot":"8:00 am","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":12152},{"TimeSlot":"8:15 am","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":13942},{"TimeSlot":"8:30 am","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0},{"TimeSlot":"8:45 am","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0},{"TimeSlot":"9:00 am","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0},{"TimeSlot":"9:15 am","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0},{"TimeSlot":"6:30 pm","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0},{"TimeSlot":"6:45 pm","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0},{"TimeSlot":"7:00 pm","AssistedCount":0,"Abandons":0,"AvgWaitTime":0}];

  $("#chart").kendoChart({

    series: [{
      data: arry.map(function (o,index) {
                    return new Date(secondsToHHMMSS(o.AvgWaitTime,index)).getTime();
                })
    }],
    valueAxis: {
      labels: {
        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:HH:mm:ss}', new Date(value)) #"
      },
      min: new Date("2020/03/01").getTime(),
      majorUnit: 20 * 60 * 1000 //
    },
    tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      template: "#= kendo.format('{0:HH:mm:ss}', new Date(value)) #"
    }
  });


function secondsToHHMMSS(totalSeconds, index) {
    var x = Math.round(totalSeconds);

    var milliseconds;
    if (index == 1) {
        milliseconds = ":01";
    } else {
        milliseconds = ":00";
    }
    var date = "2020/03/01 ";
    var value;

    var hours = Math.floor(x / 3600) < 10 ? ("00" + Math.floor(x / 3600)).slice(-2) : Math.floor(x / 3600);
    var minutes = ("00" + Math.floor((x % 3600) / 60)).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("00" + (x % 3600) % 60).slice(-2);

    value = date + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + milliseconds;
    console.log(value);
    return value;
}        
});

</script>
```

The above code working fine with Chrome browser. But not working in other browsers. Can Anyone tell me what is the wrong with my code.

this is how inside header

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Any console message in other browsers?

Comment: @vatz88 No, That is the main problem I can't figure out the real issue

Comment: Usually that means a Date error. Remove the " + milliseconds" at the end of your "secondsToHHMMSS" function.

Comment: @Strahdvonzar yes, that was the reason(after removing the milisecond its solved). I added millisecond part because, when chart data, `AvgWaitTime` getting the same data for all records, kendo chart getting stuck. that was the reason to add millisecond. can you sugest me any other way to add milliseconds to here. please.

Comment: @Adam First of all , in your "secondsToHHMMSS" you are returning a Date String and then converting it to timestamp with "new Date().getTime();".
It is better to return a Timestamp from your "secondsToHHMMSS" with your milliseconds added to it (timestamps are already in milliseconds). (Note : Apparently you need to not convert it again after return)

Secondly , pay attention on your "min" property inside your "valueAxis". This is controlling what will be shown and what not in your chart. Remove it and see what it does. Then start fiddling around it.

Comment: @Strahdvonzar Problem is from the `secondsToHHMMSS` method I can't add miliseconds. That the main issue. can you suggest me a solution how can I do that